# Converting a string array to long array

Tags: java, long-integer

I want convert value in `Info_TimeD1[]` from string array to long array and store in `ohh[]`.I found error and I can't pass this case.

```
String[] Info_TimeD1;  
String[] ohh;
int i;

int L1 = Info_TimeD1.length;

    for(int i=0;i<L1;i++)
{
     Long Timestamp1[i] = Long.parseLong(Info_TimeD1[i]); // error this line
     ohh[i] = getDateCurrentTimeZone1(Timestamp1[i]);
}
```

Comment: What error did you find?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to Long[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few different issues,

```
String[] Info_TimeD1;
String[] ohh;
// int i; <-- Duplicate variable with your for loop.

int L1 = Info_TimeD1.length;
Long[] Timestamp1 = new Long[L1]; // <-- Declare your array.
for (int i = 0; i < L1; i++) {
    Timestamp1[i] = Long.parseLong(Info_TimeD1[i]); // <-- Fixed.
    ohh[i] = getDateCurrentTimeZone1(Timestamp1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't valid Java:

```
Long Timestamp1[i] = // anything...
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to do - if you're trying to populate a single element of an existing array, you should use:

```
Timestamp1[i] = ...
```

If you're trying to declare a new variable, you should use:

```
long timestamp = ...
```

Currently your code is somewhere between the two.

As an aside, I would *strongly* advise you to start following Java naming conventions.